# Does OpenBMC have a "phone home" feature?

Tags: openbmc

Does OpenBMC provide the capability for a device-under-management to initiate an outbound connection to a management service? For example, Intel's AMT has CIRA (client initiated remote access) which allows the AMT firmware to establish a secure outbound connection (i.e. firewall friendly) to a central MPS (management presence server). This then allows devices to be centrally managed by a service outside the enterprise. Does OpenBMC provide this type of capability, or is that deemed too much of a security threat for servers?